# Counting data points in each 'pixel'

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am having issue writing a function that will scan a (for example) 10×10 pixel area for the amount of data points with a certain average.
My issue is getting a 10×10 area across the x axis while keeping the y axis at a constant and then once the x axis 'scan' is complete moving up 10 pixels on the y axis and repeating the scan on the x axis.

```
# creating a standard to compare images against.
# from corner dark region with a lack of sources.
baseline = np.mean(
           M91_master_image[0].data[1800:2000, 1800:2000]
    + 4 * (M91_master_image[0].data[1800:2000, 1800:2000].std())
)  

mst_image_data = M91_master_image[0].data

o_y = 400 
o_y2 = 2000 
o_x = 400 
o_x2 = 2000
s = 10  # pixel increments 

x_array = []
y_array = []

while o_x < o_x2: 
    # print(o_x)
    counts = mst_image_data[o_x:o_x + s, o_y:o_y + s]
    if counts.mean() > baseline: 
        x_pos_c = (o_x + (o_x + s))/2 
        # print(x_pos_c)
        x_array = np.append(x_array, x_pos_c)
        # print(o_x)
        y_pos_c = (o_y + (o_y + s))/2
        y_array = np.append(y_array, y_pos_c)
    o_y += s 
    o_x += s
    
print(x_array, y_array)
```

From the image you can see what I get is a diagonal:

[image]

Comment: How do you "get" a blue diagonal drawn in the image from this code?

Comment: If you increment the x and y position simultaneously by the same amounts, is it not to be expected that the result is a diagonal?

Comment: That's the issue. I am unsure of how to do this so it's not a diagonal but an area. All the best. Owen.